# Networking Issue or SAAS Issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, isp, saas

New here, first-time question! I am running a tracert to evv.sandata.com and I am seeing the following below. It appears AWS is not responding and I am getting a "Request timed out", from AWS. Is that correct?

```
C:\...>tracert evv.sandata.com

Tracing route to a258fae400fb0cee1.awsglobalaccelerator.com [99.83.205.13] over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     9 ms     6 ms     5 ms  ...

  2     7 ms     9 ms     9 ms  homeportal ...

  3    10 ms     8 ms     7 ms  72.234.160.2 (My ISP)

  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  5    61 ms    56 ms    57 ms  99.83.89.164 (AWS)

  6    57 ms    60 ms    58 ms  150.222.102.31

  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.

  8    62 ms    68 ms    57 ms  150.222.102.75

  9    58 ms    57 ms    63 ms  

a258fae400fb0cee1.awsglobalaccelerator.com [99.83.205.13]
```

Comment: What's your question? The fact that you get a request timed out at a few of the hops isn't necessarily indicative of a problem. Your tracert ultimately reached the final destination. Any hop in the path could merely be dropping your ICMP traffic because it's been programmed to do so, which is quite common. Tracert can be a useful tool, but in many cases it's usefulness is questionable and has led many an individual on a wild goose chase. So what's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: If the first hop that dropped your ICMP trace was really dropping traffic then every subsequent hop would show the same request timed out. The fact that that isn't happening tells me that those hops are simply dropping your ICMP traffic, because they've been programmed to do so, because responding to your ICMP traffic wastes resources that could be used to route "real" traffic.

Comment: Nobody here can tell you anything about Amazon's network, routing, router configuration, firewalls, security policies, traffic policies, etc. If you're trying to troubleshoot an issue accessing a service in AWS, tracert isn't the right tool. You're probably going to be better served using a tool like Fiddler or iPerf.

Comment: Thanks Joe. That helps a lot. The SAAS vendor said they can pull up the same info within seconds. They are on the East Coast and I am in Hawaii. Usually there is a lag of a few seconds but now its minutes. The issue points to a networking problem so I am doing what little I know how from here.

Comment: I would try something like Fiddler, iPerf, or the developer tools (network tab) in Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge (if you access this SaaS app through a web browser).